# Run Selenium Server on windows 10

Tags: php, selenium, selenium-server

I write a test case using Selenium IDE.now im running selenium server but iam getting error

I downloaded last package of Selenium RC from its official site that is called

```
selenium-html-runner-3.0.1.jar
```

Then run this code in Terminal (Iam using cmd in windows 10) :

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-<version-number>.jar
```

I got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.beust.jcommander.parameterException: The following option is required: -htmlSuite at 
com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.validateOptions(JCommander.java:321) at 
com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:283) at 
com.beust.jcommander.JCommander.parse(JCommander.java:265) at 
org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.mainInt(HTMLLauncher.java:209) 
org.openqa.selenium.server.htmlrunner.HTMLLauncher.mainInt(HTMLLauncher.java:273)
```

Please help me to fix it

Comment: IDE is old use selenium driver.

Comment: Use Selenium Driver! and pls also check browser version too... Link http://www.seleniumhq.org/download/